# If () statement in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new in R and have question on if () statement in R. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
My data look like as listed below

```
Var1    var2 
01         A
02         D
03         E
04         K
```

I need to create 2 additional variables (Var3 and Var4) based on var1. In SAS I would create var3 and var4 in following way:

```
if var1 = 01 then do; var3 = "New York";   var4= "NYC"; end; else;
if var1 = 02 then do; var3 = "Illinois";   var4= "ORD"; end; else;
if var1 = 03 then do; var3 = "Texas";      var4= "DFW"; end; else;
if var1 = 04 then do; var3 = "New Jersey"; var4= "EWR"; end; else;
```

I want to convert above if statements into R program. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var3 <- c("New York", "Illinois", "Texas", "New Jersey")[
                 match(var1, c("01","02","03","04")]
var4 <- c("NYC", "ORD", "DFW", "EWR")[
                 match(var1, c("01","02","03","04")]
```

Generally the items you will be working with are dataframes rather than the Sets you have in SAS-world. So you would have a data-object name, say `dat` and you might execute:

```
dat$var4 <- with( dat, c("NYC", "ORD", "DFW", "EWR")[
                 match(var1, c("01","02","03","04")] )
```

Comment: Agreed.  BondedDust is pretty wicked at coding `R`.

Comment: I don't need the points. You guys can man the helm for the night.

Comment: Thank you. How program will change if  var1 has duplicate and more than 100 elements?

Comment: I don't see that it would change at all. Why not pose an an example that illustrates any problems you foresee or ar encountering? It was offered as the most efficient solution in terms of code, maintainability, and compute time. It was specifically not designed as an `ifelse`-strategy because those do not scale well when the problems are larger.

Comment: Thanks BondedDust. It is hard to format text in comment therefore I will add new question.

Comment: Definitely avoid amending questions in comments, but do feel free to ask a new question or to use the edit capability to clarify an existing question.

Comment: Can I use 'for' and 'if' statement to create new variables in existing data frame based on condition?                                                                                       for (i in 1:nrow(dat$var1))
 if (dat$var1[i] == 1) { 
  var3 <- "New York" var4 <- "NYC"
  } else if (dat$var1 [i] == 2) {
    var3 <- "Illinois" var4 <- "ORD" 
  } 
}     # Note: code is not working

Comment: `for`-loops could be used and you might see people then using `if(){}else{}` within that loop but it's generally less efficient. The failure you are experiencing is probably from not assigning values to column names within a dataframe. R is different than SAS in not having a default "set" to which assignment is made. You would have needed to use: `dat$var3 <- "New York" ; dat$var4 <- "NYC"`

Comment: Thank you BondedDust. I used with statement and I am getting desired output. Would you please suggest me any reference to learn R or what is the best way to learn R quickly? I am very new in the world of R and I want to learn more.

Comment: Be careful wit `with`. It it doesn't not really accomplish assignment even if there is an assignment operator used within it. It rather establishes an environment. .Many SAS users have found Robert Muenchen's book useful. It's titled something along the lines of "R for SAS and SPSS users",

Answer (score 2):

The basic R rule I impose on myself is to store data that you might have to call upon in an appropriate structure (e.g. - `vector`s for a series of values, `list`s for related series of values of unequal lengths, `data.frame`s for related series of equal lengths etc etc).

So an appropriate structure in this case is a data.frame for related series of the same length. E.g.:

```
srcs <- data.frame(
  Var1=c("01","02","03","04"),
  state=c("New York", "Illinois", "Texas", "New Jersey"),
  code=c("NYC", "ORD", "DFW", "EWR")
)
```

Then use that store of basic information to add new variables as appropriate, e.g.:

```
dat <- cbind(dat, srcs[c("state","code")][match(dat$Var1,srcs$Var1),] )

#  Var1 var2      state code
#1   01    A   New York  NYC
#2   02    D   Illinois  ORD
#3   03    E      Texas  DFW
#4   04    K New Jersey  EWR
```

This turns a whole bunch of `if`/ `else` statements into a single call, and avoids the need for ugly looping operations.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `ifelse` (assuming that you have only four values for `var1`).

```
mydata$var3<- with (mydata, ifelse(var1 =="01", "New York" ,
              ifelse (var1 == "02", "Illinois",
              ifelse (var1 == "03","Texas" ,"New Jersey" ))))

mydata$var4<-with (mydata, ifelse (var1 =="01", "NYC",
        ifelse (var1 == "02","ORD",
      ifelse (var1 == "03", "DFW","EWR"))))
```

Comment: Thanks Metrics. What would be best way if var1 has duplicate and more than 100 elements?