# If statement in R, multiple conditions

Tags: r

I wonder how I can write this if statement correct. I have tried a lot of things, but none of them worked.

```
b <- matrix(NA,10,10)

> for (row in 1:10)
>> for (column in 1:10)
   >>> if(!is.na(a[row,column] && a==(1 || 2 || 3))
         b[row,column]==1
   >>> else
         b[row,column]==0
```

The problem is here:

```
if(!is.na(a[row,column] && a==(1 || 2 || 3))
```

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: Try `+(a %in% c(1, 2, 3) & !is.na(a))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If () statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868862/if-statement-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'a' is a `matrix` with the same dimension as 'b', we can do this without any `if/else`

```
+((a %in% 1:3) & !is.na(a))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
a <- matrix(sample(c(1:9, NA), 10*10, replace = TRUE), 10, 10)
```